# Superfish active class not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, superfish

when i click in a button, the superfish dont change the color, like i want.
HTML:

```
<div id="nav" class ="pull-right">   

    <ul id="menu-menu1" class="sf-menu sf-vertical">

                <li id="menu-item-314" class="menu-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-303" class="menu-item"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-302" class="menu-item"><a href="#">Dreams</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-301" class="menu-item"><a href="#">Vouchers</a></li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm using default css of superfish and keeps not working.

I already imported the styles superfish.css and superfish.js.
Everyting work nice, less that..

Is there any thing more that i need to do?

Comment: Seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/4kXp9/1/

The li background color changes onclick.

Comment: I didnt understand, not working here

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about what you'd like to see happening. From what I can tell, it's working as designed.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987696/how-to-add-a-superfish-menu-to-existing-pages). Maybe it will help you.

It's inside your CSS you should edit that.